# Connecting Sql-database to wcf web sevice

Tags: database, web-services, wcf

I am trying to learn how to build a web service with WCF in .Net framework 4.5 using Visual Studio 2019, and I am trying to connect my service to a database already created which I want to do operation on through that web service, my exact question is: how to open a connection between the two things using SQlConnection class?, beacause I saw the constructors of the SqlConnection but I could't understand where can we write the address/Path of our database?
It may be a little bit stupid question, but I need a better explanasion than the one that exists on the Microsoft web site.

Comment: Both Ado.net and Entity framework is capable of CURD the database. The connection string usually is configured in the configuration file, also it can be programmed in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code, which describes a void method that creates the connection string. and then we call it every time we creat a connection.
Note: *DataSource* is the server address, *IntitialCatalog* is the database name

```
private void ConnectToDB(string datasource, string initialcatalog)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBiulder ConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            DataSource = datasource,
            InitialCatalog = initialcatalog,
            IntegratedSecurity = true 


        };
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();


    }
```

Obviously we can add the other available attributes to the connection string, and modify them as we want.